# Remove XML tabs & newline within same tag in Bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have XML data like below with different name and ending tag.

This kind of format is easy to read but problematic for data extraction.

**XML source data**

```
<Device name="MotorA" 
type="stepper" 
factor="2" 
profile="high" 
SyncMode="false">

<Param name="Gain" 
type="Baic" 
PID="Standard" 
valid="true" 
version="1.2"/>
```

**Expected output**

```
<Device name="MotorA" type="stepper" factor="2" profile="high" SyncMode="false">
<Param name="Gain" type="Baic" PID="Standard" valid="true" version="1.2"/>
```

How do I remove tabs/and newlines within same tag (one tag, one line) for data extraction in a Bash script?

Environment is "Linux develop 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: In your example not only _newlines within same tag_ are removed, but also the empty line between tags. You should make clear whether this is desired.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the closing `</Device>` tag of your `<Device [...]>` node? Your XML data suggests the `<Param [...]>` node is actually a child-node instead of a sibling.

I suggest you process XML with an XML-parser, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel). Luckily `xidel` is rather forgiving for unclosed tags:

```
$ xidel -s "input.xml" -e . --output-node-format=xml
<Device name="MotorA" type="stepper" factor="2" profile="high" SyncMode="false">

<Param name="Gain" type="Baic" PID="Standard" valid="true" version="1.2"/></Device>
```

Notice the closing `</Device>` tag?

Or properly indented:

```
$ xidel -s "input.xml" -e . --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
<Device name="MotorA" type="stepper" factor="2" profile="high" SyncMode="false">
  <Param name="Gain" type="Baic" PID="Standard" valid="true" version="1.2"/>
</Device>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (where `srcdatas.xml` is a XML file containing the **xml source data** from your question).

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=""}{gsub(/\n/, " ", $0); print $0}' srcdatas.xml
```

Tested on [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about) (WSL), specifically

```
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64)
```

Inspiration came from the following question on *server**fault***

[linux - remove line break using AWK](https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it removes all of line break. Can we remove line break within same tag and make it "one tag, one line" Thanks

Comment: @AlbertLiang I wrote that it worked in my environment. I guess you have a different environment. Maybe you should [edit] your question and add more details, like the platform you are on. Are you on a Windows system? Note that I simply copied the XML from your question and pasted it into a text file that I created using [vi editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi).

Comment: Thanks for heads up. my environment is "Linux develop 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: @AlbertLiang I don't have access to a linux system. I assume the output of the above command, on your system, is a single line. If so, then try piping the output of the above command to another `awk` (or `sed`) command that inserts a newline between the `>` of the [XML] end tag and the `<` of the following start tag.

Answer (score 0):

If `ed` is available/acceptable. Note that `ed` is not a tool for parsing xml files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ed -s file.xml <<-EOF
  g/^</;/>$/j
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

Or a separate `ed` script, `script.ed`

```
g/^</;/>$/j
,p
Q
```

Then

```
ed -s file.xml < script.ed
```

*In-oneline*

```
printf '%s\n' 'g/^</;/>$/j' ,p Q | ed -s file.xml
```

Change `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing of file.xml is needed.

Answer (score 0):

This command removes all tabs and newlines, and add newline to each tag ends with `>`

```
tr -d '\t\n' < yourxml | sed -e $'s/>/>\\\n/g'
```

Tested on

- Mac bash: GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)
- Ubuntu bash: GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)